# Why my Ajax response is very slow?

Tags: ajax, jquery

I am calling an ajax function on a click event .. In the server page I am checking several functions (20). It's  taking some time, 2 to 3 minutes.

This is not a browser issue.

Why does this delay occur?
What are the probabilities?

Can you guys share your experiences?

Comment: How can i know which state of ajax making me down ,,,,,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Check your back-end queries
2. Check for non-indexed queries
3. You could be repeating some operations.

Please explain morei n detail your problem

Comment: Firebug ( Firefox Addon ) will help you do that.

Install Firebug via Tools > Addons in Firefox and then after you install it and restart Firefox, press F12 for the Firebug panel. You will then see "Console" and when active you will see all AJAX requests sent to the server, including the time it takes etc. Very helpful! Sorry for the late reply m8 hope this helps